# Retrieve data with images from list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am using linq code parsing XML file.This is my code.I want bind detail and image are list.

```
 var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
             from detail in l.Descendants("Details")
             select new Notch
             {
                 name = (string)l.Attribute("name").Value,
                 detail= l.Element("detail").Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("detailName")).ToList(),
                 Image = l.Element("detail").Elements("event_image").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("url")).ToString()
             };

 foreach (var result in query)
 {
     foreach (var detail in result.detail)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(detail);
     }  
 }
```

I tried this code but i got the output like below ..but i want the details and images are list.

```
  Raja

  System.Collection.Generic.List'1[string.system]

  Rama

  System.Collection.Generic.List'1[string.system]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting a list of strings, instead of a unique one.
Try this code in order to join every string with a new line and be able to print it properly:

```
detail = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, l.Element("detail").Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("detailName")))
```

Full code:

```
var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
             from detail in l.Descendants("Details")
             select new Notch
             {
                 name = (string)l.Attribute("name").Value,
                 detail= string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, l.Element("detail").Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("detailName"))),
                 Image = l.Element("detail").Elements("event_image").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("url")).ToString()
             };

 foreach (var result in query)
 {
     foreach (var detail in result.detail)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(detail);
     }  
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks to replay i hope your answer but i will get some error

Comment: Hi i got error like The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: try to convert the inner select to array: detail= string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, l.Element("detail").Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("detailName").ToArray()))

Comment: hi please tell me why this problem coming like that give me correct solution